# How to disallow Exchange 2010 Delivery Receipt requests?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Is there a rule or a way that this can be turned on for a certain group of individuals, such as a distribution group.

It really doesn't matter which way, I just need to have Delivery Receipt/Report turned off. I've tried unchecking "Allow Delivery Reports" in Remote Domains in EMC, but that isn't working.

I've tried setting up several rules, but that isn't working as well.

We have Exchange 2010 and need to have this disabled asap.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/02/23/3412028.aspx

Or here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/exchangesvradmin/thread/1a64437e-7d96-4d8b-99dd-9b393c273b68

You'll find there solutions how to strip the necessary headers from outgoing mails so that the receiving server doesn't send the responses. But Exchange has no built-in mechanism where you can chech/uncheck a setting.

Comment: If you look at link that you have provided, they are in regards to Read Receipts, which I have already resolved. I am looking for a resolution to stopping all "Delivery Receipts" from being sent at all.

Comment: @TesterJones If you look at the second link I have provided, it is in regards of Delivery Receipts which is not Read Receipts.

Comment: Tried the method of the second link without success. I believe that DeliveryStatusNotification Enabled $false changes the setting to receive any delivery reports such as mailbox doesn't exist. Please advise.

What I'm looking for is how to stop a Delivery Receipt within my organization. Users are sending their emails with Delivery Receipt options chosen, and we would like to have this cut out.